# Saving object caused NullPointerException in Insert statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I have a problem when saving an object with SQLite in Android.

Below is my `DAO` class:

```
public class FundkDAO implements Dao<Training> {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private SQLiteStatement insertStatement;
    private String DB_Table = "training";
    private String INSERT = "insert into " + DB_Table
        +"(" +
        "id," +
        "nameuser," +
        "kategorie," +
        "uebung," +
        "gewicht," +
        "datum" +
        ")" + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    private String SEL_ROW = 
        "id," +
        "nameuser," +
        "kategorie," +
        "uebung," +
        "gewicht," +
        "datum " +
        "from "
        + DB_Table;
    private String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + DB_Table
        + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
        + "  nameuser String, "
        + "  kategorie String, "
        + "  uebung String, "
        + "  gewicht DOUBLE, "
        + "  datum String)";

    public FundkDAO(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;
        try {
            insertStatement = db.compileStatement(INSERT);
            Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "Create INSERT product");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "NO Database, NO INSERT  TrainingsplanDao()");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long save(Training type) {
        insertStatement.clearBindings();
        insertStatement.bindString(2, type.getNameuser());
        insertStatement.bindString(3, type.getKategorie());
        insertStatement.bindString(4, type.getUebung());
        insertStatement.bindDouble(5, type.getGewicht());
        insertStatement.bindString(6, type.getDatums());        
        return insertStatement.executeInsert();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Training type) {
        db.delete(DB_Table, "id" + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(type.getId())});
        db.close();     
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Training type) {
        db.delete(DB_Table, "id" + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(type.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Training get(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Training get(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Training> getAll() {
        List<Training> list = new ArrayList<Training>();
        Cursor cs = db.rawQuery(SEL_ROW, new String[]{});
        if (cs.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list.add(buildProductFromCursor(cs));
            } while (cs.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void createTable() {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        try {
            insertStatement = db.compileStatement(INSERT);
            Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "Create INSERT MAKROS");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "NO Database, FAIL createTable(MAkrosDAO())");
        }
    }

    private Training buildProductFromCursor(Cursor cs) {
        Training makros = null;
        if (cs == null) {
            Log.e("Internal Error", "no cursor  MakrosDao()");
        } else { 
            makros  = new Training(cs.getInt(0),cs.getString(1),cs.getString(2),cs.getString(3),cs.getDouble(4),cs.getString(5));
        }
        return makros;
    }
}
```

Here is the initalisation:

```
db = new OpenHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();
FundkDAO tdDao = new FundkDAO(db);
```

The table is created in the OpenHelper class so the problem cannot be there. 
When saving an object, I get a `NullPointerException` in `FundkDAO` Save method.

Here's the LogCat output:

```
09-18 13:42:25.020: E/SQLiteLog(6314): (1) table training has no column named datum
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314): Process: com.example.trainingslog, PID: 6314
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trainingslog/com.example.trainingslog.UebungsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at com.example.trainingslog.FundkDAO.save(FundkDAO.java:68)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at com.example.trainingslog.UebungsActivity.onCreate(UebungsActivity.java:43)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-18 13:42:25.030: E/AndroidRuntime(6314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
```

Comment: Instead of SQLiteDatabase, use ORMLiteDB which helps you easily store and fetch data.

Comment: What's line FundkDAO.java:68?

Comment: In general one would INSERT without the AUTOINCR id, which in JDBC can be retrieved from the just executed statement with `getGeneratedKeys()`.

Comment: @Dhruti it is the buildProductFromCursor(Cursor cs)  method

Comment: @JoopEggen when I remove AUTOINCREMENT 
Then i get 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "id": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: id,nameuser,kategorie,uebung,gewicht,datum from training

Comment: Sorry, I meant to remove the `id` column from the INSERT, as that will be generated.

Comment: @JoopEggen i tried it out but still not works nullpointer at save(type) in FundkDAO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Forgot "select term in this method:

```
private String SEL_ROW = 
    "id," +
    "nameuser," +
    "kategorie," +
    "uebung," +
    "gewicht," +
    "datum " +
    "from "
    + DB_Table;
```